# race condition with file getAbsolutePath() java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, race-condition

It seems like I have a race condition when I call `file.getAbsolutePath()` in my Java program.

In one thread I am processing a file and when it is finished processing I am changing the filename and moving it to another directory on the UNIX file system.

In a separate thread running in parallel I am attempting to open this file that is being processed and reading its contents.  In 99% of use cases this operation is fine however I have noticed sometimes that the operation fails with a `FileNotFound` exception.

When I catch this exception I am logging the `file.getAbsolutePath()` value and I see the value is the concatenation of the path of the file in the processed directory it has been moved to and also the path of the file in the directory it was present in before processing completed.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem in the past and how did you get around it?

Thanks

Comment: No one can tell what your problem is with so little information.  You appear to have decided that it is the call to getAbsolutePath(), but we have no evidence of that, and it is much less likely that it causes any kind of race condition than that you have made a programming mistake.

Comment: @JoshDavies Note that File is not declared to be thread safe, so you must not share it between threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: Can you write a short program that demonstrates this issue? (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to synchronize the file access from separate threads using a class that does this, let's call it `FileManager`.

First option in implementing the `FileManager` is to use an exclusive lock. For example:

```
class FileManager {

   private Object lock = new Object();

   public void processFile() {
       synchronized(lock) {
            ...
       }
   }

   public void readFile() {
      synchronized(lock) {
            ...
      }  
   }
}
```

If there are many more readers than writers a Read/Write Lock is more suitable as it allows multiple concurrent readers but only a single writer:

```
class FileManager {

   private final Lock readLock;
   private final Lock writeLock;

   FileManager() {
       ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(false);
       readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
       writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
   }

   public void processFile() {
       writeLock.lock();

       try {
            ...
       }
       finally {
          writeLock.unlock();
       }
   }

   public void readFile() {
       readLock.lock();

       try {
            ...
       }
       finally {
          readLock.unlock();
       } 
   }
}
```